# How to get uploaded bytes from internetarchive.upload function?

Tags: python, file-upload, archive, tqdm

I wanted to upload files from my local pc to archive.org. I searched and found their `internetarchive` module for python. I read the documentation and managed to upload my files to the site. It was quite easy. But all it was done in console. I wanted to make a PyQt5 GUI so that will make it easier to upload. But without any upload progress bar, it cannot be thought. There's a tqdm progress bar in console if I add `verbose=True` arg in upload function. But what about the GUI? tqdm cannot be showed on GUI. **So I need to at least know how much byte/part of the file has uploaded**. Then I can make a progress bar with it.

I tried this:

```
from internetarchive import configure, get_item, upload, get_files
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from random import choices
from time import sleep

def get_indentifier(l=20):
    while 1:
        identifier = ''.join(choices(ascii_letters + digits, k=l))
        if not get_item(identifier).exists:
            return identifier

def upload_callback(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)

configure('email', 'password')
print('Logged in')

identifier = get_indentifier()

print('Uploading...')
upload(identifier, ['file-sm.zip'], verbose=True)
print('Uploaded')

print('Proccessing...')

found = False
while not found:
    sleep(5)
    files = [i for i in get_files(identifier, ['file-sm.zip'])]
    found = bool(files)

print('Done!')
print('URL:', files[0].url)
```

And got this output:
[image: the output i got]